# <a href="page.html> and <a href="page.php>: do these both trigger an interaction with the web server?

Tags: php, html

I have to solve this problem:

```
Explain what the following code snapshots do, and for each specify
whether it triggers an interaction (of the client/browser) with the server or
it is executed at the client side.  

    (iv) <a href="page.html">click here</a>  
    (v) <a href="page.php">click here</a>
```

Now, respectively they call for page.html and page.php from the web server. My instinct says this counts as an interaction (request-receive) of the client with the server in both cases, but the way the question is laid out seems to suggest that perhaps only the php link truly counts as an interaction.

Could anyone confirm the correct interpretation and perhaps clarify what counts as an interaction with the server.

Comment: Seriously it looks very small point but its a broad topic like can be controlled by .htaccess, may be have two files , may be it is configured to excute php even when extension is html a loot of things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both trigger an interaction with the server, as your instinct said.
Without knowing the server setup, you don't even know if the HTML-file is served unmodified, or if the request is being rewritten and processed by any server side scripting language.

The question explicitly says the other option is being executed at the client side, which is definitely wrong for both. The only exception would be when the click event is intercepted, but that requires more code on the client side and that would have to be part of the question.

Comment: Thanks, I think this covers the scope of question!

Answer (score 0):

The code itself does no server interactions. Browser uses this code to draw a hyperlink, still no server interaction. As soon as the user clicks any of the links, the interaction between browser and server is triggered (no matter if it is a `.html` or `.php`, the server receives the request and decides how to handle it).

If the page is opened locally as `file://C:/.../xxx.html`, it interacts directly with the localhost, I don't know if this is considered a server interaction... The question seems a bit unclear to me.

Comment: "The code itself does no server interactions", that's right - but a click on that code does *trigger* an interaction with the server. Whether the server runs on localhost should not matter, I would say.

Comment: It *might* trigger a server interaction but it depends on the caching rules.